# "Die Hände vor das Gesicht geschlagen (,) setzte er sich auf den Stuhl" => Komma ja oder nein?

Tags: comma

Kann mir hier jemand sagen, ob bei Satzkonstruktionen wie den folgenden ein Komma benötigt wird?

> "Die Hände vor das Gesicht geschlagen (,) setzte er sich auf den Stuhl"

> "Noch immer wackelig auf den Beinen (,) klammerte sie sich am Geländer fest"

Solltet ihr mehr Infos zu der Art von Satzkonstruktion haben, gerne her damit! :)

Danke!

LG
Earthlings

Answer (score 7):

Nach den amtlichen Rechtschreibregeln, § 78, Ziffer 3 (Infinitiv-, Partizip- oder Adjektivgruppen), ist ein Komma möglich aber nicht nötig. Der Beispielsatz dort lautet:

> Durch eine Tasse Kaffee gestärkt(,) werden wir die Arbeit fortsetzen.

Comment: Vielen lieben Dank! :)